# estimates Gaussian moments

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, integration, normal-distribution

Let $X_i \sim N(0,\sigma_i^2)$. Let $k\geq0$ be a fixed integer. I would like to compute
$$A:=E[|X_1-X_2|^k|X_2|^k]$$

My idea was
\begin{align*}
A=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|x_1-x_2|^k |x_2|^k e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_1^2}|x_1|^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_2^2}|x_2|^2}dx_1dx_2\\
=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|z_1|^k |z_2|^k e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_1^2}|z_1+z_2|^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_2^2}|z_2|^2}dz_1dz_2\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}|z_2|^k e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_2^2}|z_2|^2} E[|Z_1|^k]dz_2
\end{align*}
where $Z_1\sim N(-z_2,\sigma_1^2)$. Using Kummer's confluent hypergeometric fuction (denoted by $M(a,b,z)$) we have that the non-central moments of a r.v. $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ are:
$$E[|X|^k] = \sigma^k 2^{k/2} \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{ k+1 }{2} \right)}{\sqrt{\pi}}M(-\frac{k}{2},\frac{1}{2},-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}).$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
A=& \int_{\mathbb{R}}|z_2|^k e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_2^2}|z_2|^2} E[|Z_1|^k]dz_2\\
=& C_k \sigma_1^k \int_{\mathbb{R}}|z_2|^k e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_2^2}|z_2|^2}M(-\frac{k}{2},\frac{1}{2},-\frac{z_2^2}{2\sigma_1^2})dz_2
\end{align*}
where $C_k$ is the constant depending on $k$. If $M$ happens to be bounded for this case. Then I can get the following bound
\begin{align*}
A=&  C_k \sigma_1^k \int_{\mathbb{R}}|z_2|^k e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_2^2}|z_2|^2}M(-\frac{k}{2},\frac{1}{2},-\frac{z_2^2}{2\sigma_1^2})dz_2\\
&\leq \widetilde{C}_k\sigma_1^k \sigma_2^k.
\end{align*}

Is this procedure correct? If not, does anyone have any idea on how to find bound for $A$ depending on $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> **Question:**
> Let $X_i \sim N(0,\sigma_i^2)$. I would like to compute
> $E[|X_1-X_2|^k|X_2|^k]$

Bounds shmounds¡? For given values of integer $k$, it is possible to obtain exact closed-form solutions. In particular, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent (which appears to be your intention), the joint pdf of $(X_1,X_2)$, say $f(x_1,x_2)$, is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/jointpdfx1x2.png))</sub>

Then, $E\big[\,\big|X_1-X_2\big|^k \,\big|X_2\big|^k \, \big]$ can be derived with:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/exactkthsolution.png))</sub>

where I am using the `Expect` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to do the nitty-gritties.

For example, the solution when $k = 2$ is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/k2solution.png))</sub>

Here are the solutions corresponding to $k = 1$ to 6:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/solutionsk1tok6.png))</sub>

There is no problem deriving higher 'moments', if required.

**Notes**

1. If a general solution is required for arbitrary $k$, it may perhaps be possible to obtain same via induction, treating the even and odd $k$ cases separately.
2. As disclosure, I should perhaps add that I am one of the authors of the software function used above.

Comment: Actually what I am aiming at is a more general expression: $E[\prod_{j=1}^m |X_{j}-X_{j+1}|^k]$ where the last one $X_{m+1}=0$ and each $X_j \sim N(0,\sigma_j^2)$. I thought that looking at the case $m=2$ would be enough. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: That is a different question ...

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking that an upperbound is enough, since then iteratively one could upperbound the whole product. That's why I presented the case $m=2$, to simplify. I just wonder if, in some way or another, one could prove $E[|X_1-x_2|^k|X_2|^k]\leq C \sigma_1^k \sigma_2^k$ then the more general problem would be solved. Nevertheless, it seems that in your computations one gets $E[|X_1-X_2|^k|X_2|^k] \leq C \sum  \sigma_1^{i} \sigma_2^{j}$ where $i,j$ vary $i,j=1,\dots,2k$?